# How to add few classes from a jar file to my project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have a `standalone java project` in `eclipse`. I have to place  `dom4j.jar` in `META-INF\lib` directory. But as per my `Application server` considered It is already exposing all the packages except `org.dom4j`. So I have to explicitly make all the classes in `org.dom4j` package available to my aplication. Is there any way we can do this?

**UPDATE:**

I want **only few classes** from the jar to be available to my project at `run-time` **not all**.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project properties -> java build path -> libraries -> Add Jars
and add this jar

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if i add through buildpath they are available only at compile time. And I do not want all the classes to be available to my project at runtime. I want only few classes from the dom4j.jar to be available at runtime. I hope my question is clear

Comment: You can import selective classes in your code but you need to keep the jar in your lib.

Comment: Thats what the problem. If I place the complete jar with all the classes, server is throwing ClassCastException because few classes are already loaded by the App server class loader@G V

Comment: Your problem is something else. Either your server is maintaining a different version of dom jar. Try deleting that and putting this one. You can't pull few class files from this jar and make them available at runtime

Comment: So you mean It's not possible?

Comment: Yes.. the classes in dom jar might have a dependency on each other. Even if you pull few class files and use with your code, it will throw NoClassDefFoundException